# Migrate Bootstrap 4 Website to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have been working on a website for my Dad for 2 months, the website is almost completed and I just realized I should have been using wordpress this whole time. I leave for school 10 months out of the year and my dad is going to have to update the website when I'm gone with no knowledge of any programming languages, which is why Wordpress is really the only solution to allow him to update the content.

Is there any way to migrate a Bootstrap 4 framework to a Wordpress template, I can't find anything about this on the internet other than people saying you can't but I want to know if anyone has ever done it. I just installed Wordpress.org not sure the difference between the .com or .org but I prefer to work off of localhost rather than online.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The short answer to your question is 'yes'.  Bootstrap is simply a framework for web design with pre-defined CSS classes. You could most definitely turn your site into a WordPress theme. As for the difference between WordPress.org and .com - the former is self hosted and gives you total control and flexibility, including the ability to run on a localhost.  The other is hosted for you online and has additional limitations.

Comment: @JustinR. Appreciate the response. I'm going to look further into doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you setup a parent theme, in the `functions.php` file, you can enqueue the bootstrap into your theme as follows:

```
<?php

// Enqueue styles and scripts.
function enqueue_scripts() {
    $template_directory_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('site', $template_directory_uri.'/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('popper', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts');
```

Feel free to remove the JavaScript if you're not taking advantage of them or the jQuery if it's already being loaded...

Also, as Justin mentioned, WordPress.com is hosted on just that, WordPress.com. The WordPress zip that you download on WordPress.org is for you to host on your own server. The latter sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Appreciate the response, I use a similar enqueue, and have already transfered the site to wordpress.org